Starting a docker container with ssh service as a non-root user
I took the semaphore docker image and via docker file I installed an ssh server. Now I'm faced with a problem:
FROM semaphoreui/semaphore:latest

USER root

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache openssh openrc

RUN echo "PermitRootLogin yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config && \
    echo "PasswordAuthentication yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config && \
    echo "semaphore:password" | chpasswd

RUN mkdir -p /var/run/sshd

RUN cd /etc/ssh && ssh-keygen -A

EXPOSE 22

USER semaphore

I make the image.
docker build . -t semaphore:ssh
When I launch the container I have to start the ssh server as root user, but I want the container to be started with semaphore user, so I am forced to launch the conatiner as a normal user but then to give an additional command via docker exec which starts the ssh server :
docker run --name semaphore_instance -d semaphore:ssh

docker exec -u0 semaphore_instance /usr/sbin/sshd -D &

Is there a way to avoid this and launching the service with no root user?

A container normally only runs a single process.  Is there a reason you want an sshd inside a container?  How do you plan to manage the host keys, user passwords, and other security concerns?  How does this relate to the application code you're writing?

I need to exec commands by a Jenkins agent on it.

That seems like an unusual use case, since anything you do manually in a running container will get lost as soon as the container exits.  Can the container set itself up, maybe via an entrypoint wrapper script?  I'm not sure what Jenkins needs to do, but does it have access to the Docker socket so that it could use docker exec for temporary changes?

jenkins and ansible must communicate in a manner, so I install an ssh server on ansible (which will use volumes so as not to miss anything) or make calls with the socket of the host environment, but I prefer ssh.

Ports 1-1023 are reserved for the root user. Can you use a different port outside that range, and specify that when connecting?

I solved with Rest API service. It look like semaphore  has a system of rest api. Thanks for nothing.

Rather than installing SSH to access semaphore you could expose port 3000 and use "Integrations".
https://semaphoreui.com/api-docs/#/project/post_project__project_id__integrations
